# Scheduled MultiTasking With MultiThreading without overlapping of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, multitasking

I have 5 parameterized threads pointing to 5 folders where the parameter would be the name of the folder. Let's say FolderNames are A, B, C, D, and E.

Each folder will have multiple files on which certain operations need to be performed.

The operation to be performed on all the files under each folder will be the same i.e the Task will be the same. This entire thing needs to be constantly running i.e it has to be in a Schedule.

Things I have tried :

1. Scheduled with MultiThreading (i.e 5 parameterized threads working on the same Task) -> but this will cause overlapping of threads as the task is common and desired output won't be generated.
2. Scheduled with MultiTasking i.e by creating an individual class for each folder which implements Runnable and using executor.scheduleAtFixedRate for each class. This will result in Sync operation which means until the operation on the 1st folder isn't over, processing of the other 4 folders won't start. We can't increase the corePoolSize in newScheduledThreadPool as it will create same overlapping issues like Point 1.

So I am looking for help to solve this issue where my threads don't overlap on the underlying tasks.

[Summary of above problem in Pictorial Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpSYg.png)

## Dummy code for scenario 2:

```
class FolderA implements Runnable{
    private final String fileName;

    FolderA(String fileName){
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ScheduleJob.insideRun(fileName);
    }
}

class FolderB implements Runnable{...}
class FolderC implements Runnable{...}
class FolderD implements Runnable{...}
class FolderE implements Runnable{...}

public class ScheduleJob{
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    
    FolderA folderA = new FolderA("folderA");
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(folderA, 60,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    FolderB folderB = new FolderB("folderB");
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(folderB, 60,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    --and same for Folder  C D and E
    
     public static void insideRun(String folderName){
     
     //Contains call to various operations that need to 
     be perfomed on each file present in Folder A B C D and E
     
     Operation order : Read, Process, Write for each file
     
     }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does "but this will cause overlapping of threads as the task is common and desired output won't be generated" mean?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple threads if you don't want them to overlap?

Comment: The task on the underlying files  involves a lot of reading, writing, processing and generation of outputs. The threads behave eratically and start picking next files even if the operation is not completed for previous file.

Comment: Because they were overlapping I moved to solution 2 which was multitasking but then it performs in Sync fashion which will slow down the entire process as a big picture

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your code, not with multithreading. Can you please post your code? A [mcve] would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: class FolderA implements Runnable{
    private final String fileName;

    FolderA(String fileName){
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ScheduleJob.insideRun(fileName);
    }
}

class FolderB implements Runnable{...}
class FolderC implements Runnable{...}
class FolderD implements Runnable{...}
class FolderE implements Runnable{...}

Comment: public class ScheduleJob{
 ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 
    FolderA folderA = new FolderA("folderA");
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(folderA, 60,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 
 
 
 --and same for Folder B C D and E
 
  public static void insideRun(String folderName){
  
  //Contains call to various operations that need to 
 be perfomed on each file present in Folder A B C D and E
  
  Operation order : Read, Process, Write for each file
  
  }
}

Comment: Can you add the code to the question. Because it hard to read as comment.

Comment: Added the same to the question :)

Comment: @AashkaKotecha - And is that a [mcve]?

Comment: You have never explained “overlapping”. Do you mean that you want processing of folder A to not impede or block processing of folder B, and so on?

Comment: 'Multithreading without overlapping of threads' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is not clear, but I am guessing you want the processing of files in one folder to not hinder or block the processing of files in the other folders.

## Multiple `ExecutorService` objects

Create more than one `ExecutorService` objects. Each executor service is focused on a single folder. If you have five folders, have five executor services, one executor service per folder.

If you want only one file per folder to be processed at a time make each executor service single-threaded.

Define your task (your `Runnable` or `Callable`) as taking an argument indicating which folder to process.

```
public void FileProcessor implements Runnable
{
    // Constructor
    public FileProcessor( Path path ) { … } 

    // Implement `Runnable`
    @Override
    public void run() { … }
}
```

Define your folders.

```
List< Path > folders = List.of( pathToA, pathToB, … ) ;
```

Feed those to constructors of executor services.

```
List< ExecutorService > executorServices = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( Path folder : folders )
{
    ExecutorService es = Executors. newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
    executorServices.add( es ) ;
    es.submit( new FileProcessor( folder ) ) ;
}
```

Then use that collection `executorServices` to gracefully shut down all the executor services.

For scheduled executor services, same idea. Change the type from `ExecutorService` to `ScheduledExecutorService`. Call `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`. Change `submit` method to one of the schedule methods.

Be aware that even the solution presented in this Answer does *not* guarantee that all folders will be processed with equal effort. Each executor service will be backed by its own thread(s). When a thread is scheduled for execution on a CPU core, and for how long, is up to the whim of the host OS and the JVM.

We as Java programmers have no direct control of how much work is performed by each thread, or what order. At runtime, it is entirely possible that Folder B might process a dozen files while Folder A gets only three files done, and Folder C gets none done. Generally you will see the work average out over time, but may vary in the short-term.

Comment: Hi Basil, Yes this is exactly what I did. I created 5 separate executor objects and that helped me get my target. Each executor object focuses on each folder as you rightly pointed and they have a single parameterized thread.

Comment: @AashkaKotecha  Actually, it is the task (Runnable/Callable) that is parameterized, not the thread. This is an important distinction as the point of the executors framework is to relieve us of the burden of dealing with `Thread`.

Comment: @AashkaKotecha  Glad that worked out for you. Also, check back because I may post an edit showing a variation on this idea using the virtual threads (fibers) hopefully coming to Java through Project Loom.

Comment: Yes indeed a good point.. the task is parameterized and not the thread. Thank you so much for the help and good learning point :)

Comment: One more doubt if you can please answer to it. With the above approach of using separate executor like below
=====================
                                      ScheduledExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
=====================

I have created 5 such executors for each Folder and thread pool has single thread. So a single thread will monitor each folder and will perform file operations on all underlying files. But it is getting extremely slow as the file operations are large and number files are more too. What other solution could be implemented here?